# Join SQL Server Showing Duplicate Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to ask something about joining query. I have a query like this:

```
SELECT b.compilecodingid, 
       a.subjobfamily, 
       b.position, 
       b.nocoding, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN (SELECT Count(0) 
                 FROM   trlspbia 
                 WHERE  learningsystemid = a.learningsystemid 
                        AND compilecodingid = b.compilecodingid 
                        AND moduleid = '2018081616230361362303614'
                        AND learningroadmap = 'Basic') > 0 THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 
         END ) AS CountPickPBIA 
FROM   trlsplanning a, 
       trcompilecodingheader b 
WHERE  a.learningsystemid = b.learningsystemid 
       AND a.position = b.position 
       AND a.learningsystemid = '2018081513283162000000001'
       order by CountPickPBIA desc
```

[image: Result Here]

I know it's because Column Position on Table TrLsPlanning has more than 1 data, 
Anyone can help me to find the solution?
Thank you.

Comment: use JOIN instead and can you show some sample input data?

Comment: i upload the result as image

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: That's output result, I am asking for input

Comment: What is the question? How to avoid duplicates? Try `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The input just a.LearningSystemId as PKFK from 2 tables

Comment: @jarlh Thankss! i thought distinct just for 1 column.

Comment: I would also urge you to use either camel or pascal case in your object and column names. It is so hard to read text in a single case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably `select distinct`:

```
SELECT cch.compilecodingid, p.subjobfamily, cch.position,  cch.nocoding, 
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM trlspbia s
                          WHERE s.learningsystemid = p.learningsystemid AND
                                s.compilecodingid = ccb.compilecodingid AND
                                s.moduleid = '2018081616230361362303614' AND
                                s.learningroadmap = 'Basic'
                         )
             THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
        END) AS CountPickPBIA 
FROM  trlsplanning p JOIN
      trcompilecodingheader cch
      ON p.learningsystemid = cch.learningsystemid AND
         p.position = cch.position
WHERE p.learningsystemid = '2018081513283162000000001'
ORDER BY CountPickPBIA DESC;
```

`SELECT DISTINCT` incurs its own overhead.  But without more information about the structure and contents of the table, this is the simplest solution.

Note other changes in the query:

- Table aliases are abbreviations for table names, rather than being arbitrary letters.
- The `JOIN` syntax is fixed, to use modern, proper, and **standard** `JOIN`/`ON`.
- *All* columns are qualified with the table alias, particularly those in the correlated subqueries.
- The subquery uses `EXISTS` rather than `COUNT(*)`.  This is both more efficient and it probably better expresses the logic you want.